# For protease, lipase, and amylase, include an image of the chemical, and the chemical that it operates

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, enzymes

I have no idea how to find a picture for these enzyems. My teacher did not explain the chemical reaction and I am really lost. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to the site. The chemical reaction? What chemical reaction are you looking for? Also, have you tried Google for finding an image?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad; protease is a family of enzymes which  performs protein digestion aka proteolysis; same goes to lipase and amylase for lipids and sugars respectively. These enzymes/proteins have a complex [chemical structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_structure). If you want to see the structure of proteins or enzymes I would recommend [RCSB PDB database](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/home/home.do). You can search for protein structure by name,PDB ID, sequence etc. in this database. It also gives detailed information about that protein.

For example a search for `Serine proteases` ( proteases that have serine bonded at the active site) will give you [458 strutural hits](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/results/results.do?qrid=DB727361&tabtoshow=Current). There are different parameters such as organism, taxonomy etc available to refine your search

> An image of HIV-1 Protease

[D30N tethered HIV-1 protease dimer/saquinavir complex](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=4Q5M) (PDB ID=4Q5M)

[image]